# Как стилизовать яндекс карту?

Tags: javascript, html, css

Подскажите возможно ли так стилизовать яндекс карту? или какие-то стили сделать будет невозможно? api читал, но карты так некогда не стилизовал, только базово(поменять цвет, иконку и тд)
https://i.stack.imgur.com/kGpDU.png

Comment: Вот ссылка [на доки](https://yandex.com/dev/maps/mapkit/doc/dg/concepts/style.html), там вроде то, что вам нужно.